# How do I change the syntax highlighting of feature files for Cucumber JVM Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Using Eclipse Mars, my feature files currently have very limited options for syntax coloring (refer to screenshot)

[image]

I would like to change the syntax highlighting to closely match that of Intellij which is so much more better (see screenshot)

[image]

I could not find any option to change this in Eclipse. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Details: 
-Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 
  -Cucumber JVM Plugin

-IntelliJ 2017.2.3
    -plugin: Cucumber for java

Comment: other than asking you to check if you have the right plugin, I can't offer any help :( https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/90

Comment: Eclipse Mars was released 2015. Maybe the actuality of the Cucumber plugin is different, too,

Comment: Update Eclipse and your Cucumber plugin. You will then have proper highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eclipse Oxygen, it is under

"Preference" - "Appearance" - "Color and fonts" - "Gherkin".

For IntelliJ(2018.2 community), it is under

"Settings" - "Editor" - "Color Scheme" - "Cucumber".

Of course, only when you install the plugin.

Comment: Anyone has an idea how to change the background color of errors in the features editor, such as when a binding has broken? As it is in the current version of Cucumber plug-in 1.0 the white text has a yellow background when it's erroneous, making it harder to fix.